# Source and Sink Configuration for Arroyo Streaming Service

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming

I am unable to Create a Kafka Source Connection in Arroyo UI without getting an error saying

**Connected to Kafka
Fetched topic metadata
Waiting for messages
No messages received from Kafka within 30 seconds**

I have red-panda running in my local Docker on port 19092, similarly I ran Arroyo in my local Docker using the following command

`docker run -p 4040:8000 ghcr.io/arroyosystems/arroyo-single:latest`

Now in the Arroyo UI I am able to see options to Create Connections and Pipeline.

So, I tried Creating a Connection "Source" for one Kafka Topic, while creating the connection I gave

**Bootstrap Servers** as **host.docker.internal:19092**

and selected following

**Topic** where I was producing the data (test)
**Offset** as **earliest**
**Read mode** as **read_commited**

**Data format** as **unstructured json**

**Connection name** as **test_1**

Now before clinking on Test Connection I ensured that data is getting published on Red Panda topic, and I clicked on Test Connection. From which received the following result.

**Connected to Kafka
Fetched topic metadata
Waiting for messages
No messages received from Kafka within 30 seconds**

As per my understanding it is not able to receive message from Red Panda. What changes are required here to fix this issue?